# design for the savvy user or the 'stupid' user

Tags: audience, decision-making

When brainstorming features with stakeholders i commonly come across 2 kinds of reasoning

1 being this is feature is so obvious that the user will get it, maybe because they use other apps. The other being that the user really needs to be guided when using the feature as they wont get it.

Using both these to logic could just about justify anything. So under what circumstances should each of this logic be used? For instance if you are designing ux for an older audience using the  later reasoning would be understandable. but what if the audience is broader.

Comment: what do you know about your user? in which situation will they use your app? to give you a good example, I have an engineer friend and uses her phone everyday with different apps. She uses the pinterest app. She was trying to find for 10 minutes where she could see her boards. It is not that she was stupid, she was just very tired and everything seemed difficult at the point of the day.

Comment: Have you looked into [Onboarding](https://blinkux.com/blog/up-running-3-tips-for-an-awesome-onboarding-ux/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer to this question has two layers.

#### The Business layer

The first, very important one is **how it matches your business.** Attempts to satisfy all Users may very often lead to deteriorating the experience of the most business-wise important group.

Of course, various groups of Users may allow you to reach various business goals. For example, you may want to have Users with paid accounts because they build up your revenue streams, but on the other hand the free ones build up the audience and may allow you to dominate the market.

In other words, the answer to the question which ones should be supported by you more is a question which ones are more important, and **this is a business, not UX decision**.

It does not mean that you should choose just one group of Users, though. Depending on your strategic goals, it will most probably be a mix of them. If your Product is mainly focused on growth, probably getting the less tech-savvy Users on board is very important, but the ROI is probably important as well.

Once you know what your strategic goals are, you will probably know which ones need to be supported and which of them need to be supported more. This leads us to the **second layer of the question: how to do it**.

Some of the options I could suggest would be:

#### Getting to know the kind of User you from the very beginning.

You can do it in several ways, for example, if this is a tool that can be used both personally and professionally, and you allow logging in via Facebook and Google Apps account, the Users that log in via Google account may be detected as "probably pro", so you could make some more professional elements more prominent for them.

Should guessing if User is "rather pro" or "rather newbie" not fit your Product, you can still **ask them about it.** You can do it at the app start, using various kinds of questions, for example:

- *"Are you going to use this application for personal or professional purposes (or both)?"* - this may give you a clue on which features you should put more stress in further onboarding.
- *"Would you like to see a little tutorial?"* - by asking this question you allow User to decide if they want to go through it quite directly.

#### Onboarding vs. tutorial around the interface

There are various approaches here:

- Of course, you can provide an **onboarding** that would extensively walk user through the features, but before they get the context of them. In case of a complex app this leads to a situation when they would read the first two screens quite carefully, then press [Skip] several times, and then find themselves wondering how to do basic things. This is why sometimes onboardings do not work very well.
- Then you could **walk User through the interface** by displaying an overlay with information "Here you can do this" and "Here you can do that". This approach as also has its disadvantages - it may be annoying for those who would like to just start using it. So probably providing **an option to stop showing these overlays** would be something that would really support the "more pro" Users.
- The above walkthrough may be either triggered once, when User approaches the app for the first time, or multiple times, **as they approach specific features**. I would err on the side of using the latter, because it would adapt to the actual context the User is in better, while not causing the context-less cognitive overload at the beginning.
- Of course, it can be **a mix of onboarding and walkthrough** - but in both cases, to support "more pro" Users, you should allow skipping it and giving an option "Stop showing tips.". Plus, remember that the level of walkthrough may be adapted to the User type you have detected before (should you be able to do it).

#### On demand assistant to let them learn ('cause they did not before)

Users often **skip both onboardings and feature walkthroughs and then they have questions**. What is more, simply displaying an onboarding or feature walkthrough does not guarantee that they know how to use the app.

Therefore, to top it up, you may consider providing an **on-demand assistant**. It could be an icon within the interface, that would allow Users to learn how to use the features available in the particular screen. You can give it some personality, so that they feel that they are cared about (just be careful to not make it as cheesy Mr. Clippy). This would not only support the cases when they are confused but also when they want to learn something new.